# Why does setting explicit 'null' values fail for JDBC Update operation?

Tags: java, jdbc

I am trying to update some attributes with `null` values. But it always error. Here is my code

```
// deleting records of column overtime, medical, bonus, other and totalamount
try {
        String deleteQuery = "update paydb.allowance set "
        + "overtime = ?, "
        + "medical = ?,"
        + "bonus = ?,"
        + "other = ?,"
        + "totalamount = ?"
        + "where emp_id = ?";

        PreparedStatement dpst = conn.prepareStatement(deleteQuery);
        dpst.setNull(1, java.sql.Types.DOUBLE);
        dpst.setNull(2, java.sql.Types.DOUBLE);
        dpst.setNull(3, java.sql.Types.DOUBLE);
        dpst.setNull(4, java.sql.Types.DOUBLE);
        dpst.setNull(5, java.sql.Types.DOUBLE);
        dpst.setString(6, txt_search.getText());

        dpst.executeUpdate();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Record deleted successfully");
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
```

Comment: What is the error? Also, are those columns nullable in DB?

Comment: Could you tell me how to update any column with null value in java using PreparedStatment ?

Comment: Well, what you're doing looks correct from high level. But unless you provide the DB table definition (column types, nullable or not etc) it's difficult to figure out the issue. Also, "it always error" doesn't give enough information to analyze. Provide the actual error message/stacktrace.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'emp_id = 'PMS290" at line 1. This is the error

Comment: The table is set to Nullable : YES

Comment: You're missing a space before `where`, that's the issue.

Comment: Yes, yes, yes its working. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Vasan Could you provide the missing space comment as a valid answer? Would help others quickly spot this question is solved. ;)

Comment: @MWiesner I added it as a comment because I thought it would fall under the "issues caused by typos" category. Such questions normally get closed.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
        String deleteQuery = "update paydb.allowance set "
        + "overtime = ?,"
        + "medical = ?,"
        + "bonus = ?,"
        + "other = ?, "
        + "totalamount = ? "
        + "where emp_id = ? ";
    enter code here
        PreparedStatement dpst = conn.prepareStatement(deleteQuery);
        dpst.setNull(1, java.sql.Types.DOUBLE);
        dpst.setNull(2, java.sql.Types.DOUBLE);
        dpst.setNull(3, java.sql.Types.DOUBLE);
        dpst.setNull(4, java.sql.Types.DOUBLE);
        dpst.setNull(5, java.sql.Types.DOUBLE);
        dpst.setString(6, txt_search.getText());

        dpst.executeUpdate();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Record deleted successfully");
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
```